# Rails 4: Delete association column on ActiveRecord delete call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Blog` table and an `Import` table. In the `Import` table, when someone imports data, the column `blog_id` gets populated with the corresponding `blog`.

I offer the possibility to `delete` a `blog`, but I'd like to keep a trace of the imports. So I need to delete the corresponding `blog_id` entries otherwise I'll get an error like this:

```
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "imports"
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common solution is by using `soft delete`. Basically this means, you add another column in your `Blog` table, called `deleted`, and set default to `false`.

Then instead of calling `@blog.destroy` in your controllers, you set the `deleted` column to `true`.

Then you need to update your blog queries, and include `.where(deleted: false)` to make sure your user only see `not deleted` blogs.

Comment: Either that or move these entries to a table that does not enforce the referential integrity so that you can retain a history and even roll back if needed.